# Added Core Data To Existing App, Now Can't Resolve Errors

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I added Core Data to my existing app.  I added the methods and properties in the App Delegates and I added `#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>` to the prefix file.

But I am still getting the following errors:[image]

Here is the link for the bigger picture: http://www.box.net/shared/static/zfd2bkxy23.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using xcode 4, you can add frameworks by clicking your project on the left (all the way on top of your files), going to 'Build Phases' and then opening 'Link Binary With Libraries'. There, click the plus, and select what framework to add.

I dont know exactly how it went in xcode 3, but you can find that everywhere on the web ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the CoreData framework to your project as well. To the left you'll find "Frameworks", right click, Add->Existing Frameworks...

Comment: I tried this but don't see an option to add frameworks.  It just brings up the finder.  Do I have to find the framework manually in the finder?